# How to receive an email on server? Better using Python or Perl

Tags: python, perl, email

I've checked so many articles, but can't find one for server to server email receiving. I want to write a program or some code just acts as an email receiver, not SMTP server or something else.

Let's suppose I have a domain named example.com, and a gmail user user@gmail.com sends me an email to admin@example.com, or a yahoo user user@yahoo.com sends me an email to test@example.com. Now, what do I do to receive this email? I prefer to write this code in Python or Perl.

Regards,
David

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Do you want to get the mail yourself, or to make the code do something with the received mail?

Comment: use fetchmail(1), and not write a line of code. Though I have written an ad-hoc fetchmail in perl based on Net::POP3.

Comment: Did you configure `MX` records correctly? http://www.petri.co.il/configure_mx_records_for_incoming_smtp_email_traffic.htm

Comment: I'm sorry, but from your question and your comments below it's clear you have no idea how email works, and as a result of this you are asking nonsensical and contradictory questions. As far as I can figure out, you want to install a mail server. Look for which and how on serverfault.com.

Comment: I just tried many times, it seems SMTPServer can do this. I will have further testing.

Comment: @Sinan - Seeing how viruses are propagated via e-mail, I'd be a bit cautious about getting mail advice from a server called "Petri" :))))

Comment: Why are some respondents being so rude? I have exactly the same question as David. I want to use emails to trigger application logic (e.g. email a file to my personal webspace file system). All the solutions offered here seem to be related to sending email, or downloading email from a host. What David and I want is a scripting equivalent to maillets like Apache James http://james.apache.org/ . A python API would be great, but I don't see any examples.

Comment: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2005-February/296672.html

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/smtpd.html

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/smtpd/

Comment: I don't have a mail server. I want to be a mail server, so I can't use pop to reveive mail

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

Net::SMTP libraries (including [Net::SMTP::Server](http://search.cpan.org/~macgyver/SMTP-Server-1.1/Server.pm)).

Here's an example of using it: http://wiki.nil.com/Simple_SMTP_server_in_PERL

Answer (score 1):

"reveive" is not a word. I'm really not sure if you mean "receive" or "retrieve".

If you mean "receive" then you probably do want an SMTP server, despite your claim. An SMTP server running on a computer is responsible for listening for network requests from other SMTP servers that wish to deliver mail to that computer.

The SMTP server then, typically, deposits the mail in a directory where it can be read by the recipient. They can usually be configured (often in combination with tools such as Procmail) to do stuff to incoming email (such as pass it to a program for manipulation along the way, this allows you to avoid having to write a full blown SMTP server in order to capture some emails).

If, on the other hand,  you mean "retrieve", then you are probably looking to find a library that will let your program act as an IMAP or POP client. These protocols are used to allow remote access to a mailbox.

Comment: I am sorry, I typed a wrong word, it's "receive". I tried to use Python's SMTPServer to receive my email, but don't work.
I want to have a test on my machine, so I do a little test locally.
First, add "127.0.0.1 example.com" to /etc/hosts
Then, run my smtp server
Last, run my script to send email to admin@example.com, but I got nothing.
Then, I used Python's SMTPlib to connect to my stmp server, and send email, then I received it. But I don't think it's right. Cause if this is right, then why can't php's mail() send an email to me?

Answer (score 1):

Good article at http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2010/10/15/fake-smtp-server-with-python/ showing how to subclass smtpd.SMTPserver and how to run it.